# Font size of option in select doesn't change when I change font size of my android device

Tags: react-native, select, device, font-size

I have this form in my react-native app and when the font-size of a device is not default, the font-size of an input text and a select option looks different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xJOX.png)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write below code in your app.tsx(Your staring application file) File inside useEffect.

```
 useEffect(()=>{
   if (Text.defaultProps == null) Text.defaultProps = {};
   Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
 })
```

For above code if your device font setting change your app font change will not change it will remain same whatever you provide in your style